# How can i delete one file from cache of ImageLoader (including different resolutions)

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I have image file://...qgKEIJC5EHey5qLUEDPWazJ9QimqkeQK.jpg, it is loaded with options

```
new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(false)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build()
```

but when i delete this file, and remove it from cache

```
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.setWritable(true);
        MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(file.getAbsolutePath(), ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
        DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(file.getAbsolutePath(), ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
        if (!deleted)
            Log.d("ERROR", "");
    }
```

image loader still loading it from memory cache

```
D/ImageLoader: Display image in ImageAware (loaded from MEMORY_CACHE) [file://.../qgKEIJC5EHey5qLUEDPWazJ9QimqkeQK.jpg_430x430]
```

then i've tried to delete such file using image view size

```
int size = getImageView().getWidth();
            String cachedFile = file.getAbsolutePath() + "_" + size + "x" + size; // = file://.../qgKEIJC5EHey5qLUEDPWazJ9QimqkeQK.jpg_430x430
            MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(cachedFile, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
```

but it not worked

how can i delete all such files from cache?

Comment: did you try imageLoader.clearDiscCache();?

Comment: i need to save other images in cache (they could be very big), and i need to have their small resolutions in cache, but i need to remove one image and replace it with another with same name, but image loader after replacing shows old image from memory cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution:
i was using wrong url for local file, i forgot to add `file://` in code, cause my image url was saved as `file.getAbsolutePath()` and was not including `file://`. Also i found how i can smoothly replace original picture with cropped (in situation when cropping layer cover original picture and then it need to disappear and show already cropped image)

in adapter

```
public void setImageLoader(final ImageView imageView, final MyImage myImage) {
        final String path = "file://" + myImage.getAbsPathImage();
        final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(false) //important!
                .cacheInMemory(true) //important!
                .cacheOnDisk(true) //important!
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
        if (!myImage.isImageCropCacheUpdated()) {
            List<String> memCache = MemoryCacheUtils.findCacheKeysForImageUri(path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
            boolean cacheFound = !memCache.isEmpty();
            if (!cacheFound) {
                File discCache = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
                if (discCache != null) {
                    cacheFound = discCache.exists();
                }
            }
            if (cacheFound) {
                myImage.setIsImageCropCacheUpdated(true);
                MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
                DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(path, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
            }
        }

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(path, imageView, options);
}
```

in activity

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) pager.findViewWithTag(Constants.TAGS.IMAGEVIEW_TAG
                        + pager.getCurrentItem()); //get image view from view pager
                imageView.setImageBitmap(getCropImageView().getCroppedImage());
                imagePagerAdapter.setImageLoader(imageView, getCurrentImage()); //get cropped image from special crop image view and call setImageLoader from adapter
```

i'm not using `notifyDataSetChanged()` because image blinks in that case (dont know why), after that i call fade out animation for special crop image view and it looks great, also i'm setting cropped image to `imageView` before image loader because it can load picture for a while, and fade out animation has a fixed time period, if i will not do that - there maybe a little time when cropping layer already disappeared and cropped image still was not loaded, this not good